# Calling a macro from a macro with a variable number of arguments

Tags: elisp-macros

Say there is a `defmacro` defined like this:

```
(defmacro do-something (foo &optional bar)
  (...))
```

And then there is another one that calls it:

```
(defmacro something-else (wat baz &optional bar)
  (let ((foo (concat wat baz)))
    (do-something ...)))
```

What is the best practice for calling `do-something` from within
`something-else` with the let variable `foo`, and `bar` only if it
exists as an argument passed into `something-else`?

I know you could conditionally check the presence of `bar` like so:

```
    (if bar
        (do-something foo bar)
      (do-something foo))
```

Ideally I'm looking for some pattern where I can prepare a list of
argument variables and call `do-something` once, with something like
`(apply)` for macros, where a list variable can be turned into a
variable series of consecutive arguments. Or maybe I'm just thinking
about this in the wrong manner?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, but wouldn't simply `(when bar (do-something foo bar))` work?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't explain my question well enough. Added some more background about what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you've written, you can simply replace this:

```
(if bar
    (do-something foo bar)
  (do-something foo))
```

With this:

```
(do-something foo bar)
```

Because optional arguments default to `nil`. From the Emacs Lisp manual:

> If actual arguments for the optional and rest variables are omitted, then they always default to nil. There is no way for the function to distinguish between an explicit argument of nil and an omitted argument.

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Argument-List.html

Comment: Its my understanding that passing `bar` as `nil` into `(do-something)` is technically different than omitting the optional variable. Is this never the case?

Comment: @waymondo From the Emacs Lisp manual: "There is no way for the function to distinguish between an explicit argument of nil and an omitted argument." http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Argument-List.html You may be confusing this behavior with Common Lisp.

Comment: @nanny Nope, trying to tackle [this](https://github.com/waymondo/use-package-chords/issues/3) issue. Using the `if` condition is a hack that actually works.

Comment: @kaushalmodi That's an interesting problem, I'll look into it as well. I'm inclined to say that the Emacs manual is not lying, and this isn't a bug with Emacs, but with one of the packages involved.

Comment: @kaushalmodi I think I found the problem. I think it lies with the `bind-key` macro. I will open an issue/PR.

Comment: @kaushalmodi is it the fact that there is no `(or)` clause right here? https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/master/bind-key.el#L154

Comment: @waymondo Thanks, that looks like it.. just saw nanny's [PR](https://github.com/nandryshak/use-package/commit/72221c99041a7231ab3dc51c081975fdc09c27b5).